# how to send database records one by one to another page in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

i am creating a quiz system same like http://www.sqlquiz.com/ and i have problem in the result page.
i have created 4 pages

index.php ---->welcomePage where i use a varible n in query string

**index.php**

```
<p><a href="quizmain.php?n=1">Start SQL Quiz</a></p>
```

2.quizmain.php------------>this page shows questions and their options and after
getting responce for each question it will go to the process.php page where the score is calculate and every time the counter is incremented by 1 so that after reaching 10th question the final result page will be displayed

**quizmain.php**

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    require_once("connection.php");
    extract($_REQUEST);

    $number = (int) $_GET['n']; //starting value 1
    echo $number;
    $n1=rand(1,100);

    $_SESSION['RQuestionNumber']=$n1;

    $q=mysql_query("select * from quiz WHERE qno = '".$n1."'");

    $a=mysql_fetch_array($q);


    echo $a['qno'];
    echo $a['ans'];

    ?>




<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="757" height="390"><div align="center">


            <form method="post" action="process1.php">

               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="a" />
              <?php echo $a[2]?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="b" />
                <?php echo $a[3]?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="c" />
                <?php echo $a[4]?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> </label>
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="d" />
                <?php echo $a[5]?></label>
          </p>

        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p>
            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
          <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
          </form>
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
 <?php 
    session_start(); 
    require_once('connection.php');
    extract($_REQUEST);
        //Check to see if score is set_error_handler
        if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
            $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
        }

        if($_POST)
        {
            $number = $_REQUEST['number'];  //value of number is 1 initially 
            $selected_choice = $_REQUEST['question'];
            $next = $number+1; //

        $total=10;  
        $_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'];


        $q = mysql_query("SELECT ans FROM quiz WHERE qno = '".$_SESSION['RQuestionNumber']."'");
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($q);

        //$store=array();



            //Compare
            if($result[0][0] == $selected_choice){
                //Answer is correct
                $_SESSION['score']++;
            }


            //Check if last question
            if($number == $total){
                header("location: resultTable.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                header("location: quizmain.php?n=".$next); //now the value of n is 2 
            }
        }
        ?>
```

**resultTable.php**

now in this page i want to print all the questions which appear during the quiz (Same set of questions) along with the marked answer and correct ans 
i have tried using session variables but it don't work.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
            <p>Final Score: <?php echo $_SESSION['score']; ?></p>

<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

Comment: the line `$_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'];` in `process.php` looks wrong - there is no value being set - should that not be `$_SESSION['RQuestionNumber']=$number;`??

Answer (score 0):

You session value will be override each time so at last you will get last questtion id. If you want all question Ids then use array. Try this:

**quizmain.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once("connection.php");
    extract($_REQUEST);

    $number = (int) $_GET['n']; //starting value 1
    echo $number;
    $n1=rand(1,100);

    $_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'][]=$n1;

    $q=mysql_query("select * from quiz WHERE qno = '".$n1."'");

    $a=mysql_fetch_array($q);


    echo $a['qno'];
    echo $a['ans'];

    ?>




<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="757" height="390"><div align="center">


            <form method="post" action="process1.php">

               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="a" />
              <?php echo $a[2]?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="b" />
                <?php echo $a[3]?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="c" />
                <?php echo $a[4]?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> </label>
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="question" value="d" />
                <?php echo $a[5]?></label>
          </p>

        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p>
            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
          <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
          </form>
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    require_once('connection.php');
    extract($_REQUEST);
        //Check to see if score is set_error_handler
        if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
            $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
        }

        if($_POST)
        {
            $number = $_REQUEST['number'];  //value of number is 1 initially 
            $selected_choice = $_REQUEST['question'];
            $next = $number+1; //

        $total=10;  
        $last_que = $_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'][count($_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'])-1];
       // $_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'];


        $q = mysql_query("SELECT ans FROM quiz WHERE qno = '".$last_que."'");
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($q);

        //$store=array();



            //Compare
            if($result[0][0] == $selected_choice){
                //Answer is correct
                $_SESSION['score']++;
            }


            //Check if last question
            if($number == $total){
                header("location: resultTable.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                header("location: quizmain.php?n=".$next); //now the value of n is 2 
            }
        }
        ?>
```

**resultTable.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
            <p>Final Score: <?php echo $_SESSION['score']; ?></p>
            <?php
            var_dump($_SESSION['RQuestionNumber']); //You will get all question number here
            ?>

<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store arrays on sessions, so every time you run process.php you can add an array with question number and given answer, that way at the resultTable.php you could just select the 10 questions from the db and compare with the given answers.

Add into process.php:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['answers'])) {
  $answers = new array();
} else {
  $answers = $_SESSION['answers'];
}

$answers[] = array($_SESSION['RQuestionNumber'], $selected_choice);

$_SESSION['answers'] = $answers;
```

So what this code does is create an array to store question and user given answer and saves it in the session, this way you can loop this array on the resultTable and show all the question on the quiz.

PS: this is very basic code, there are a lot you need to do in order to use it on your quiz game, i.e. you should check if the array is not set from previous runs

Comment: sir i get the question Numbers and user given answers for all the questions but how can i get the questions and their correct choice using this information from the database

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Sessions for That
    simple syntax of sessions is:
        `session_start();
$_SESSION['score'] = $data;`

Now you can use your $data at another page by just starting session like this
`session_start();
echo $_SESSION['score'];`

To remove data you should destroy the session

```
session_destroy();
```